# ng-include is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I have create a simple page using AngularJs. When I'm trying to include header.htm in index.html, nothing is appearing in browser.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="">
  <div ng-include="'views/header.htm'"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

header.htm

```
<h1>Header</h1>
```

Comment: any errors in browser console?

Comment: Hope `index.html` and the `views` folder resides a same level.Syntax wise it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

You request `views/header.htm` so your file structure needs to look like this:

```
- index.html
- views
  - header.htm
```

To test your site locally use a tool like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). Or when you are on a Mac or Unix based machine you can simply run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in your projects directory.

Comment: thanks bro i have tried this , i am getting an error in console angular.js:12587 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/angular/project/views/header.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is, that your browser doesn't allow Javascript loading local files. To prevent that, use something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). This error should be gone when you're using that tool or when you upload it onto a server.

Comment: if you use linux system try navigating to your project directory and run the following command  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: now i am using node js server, in console error: 404 (not found)

Comment: When you are loading the index file or when when loadingg header.htm

Comment: server.js

    ` var express = require('express');

     var app = express();

     var bodyParser =  require("body-parser");

     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

     app.use(bodyParser.json());



     app.get('/', function(req, res){

     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + 'index.html');

     console.log("----------------");

     });

     app.listen(3000);`

Comment: I guess that would be worth another question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MfHa6/1860/) to show how it works.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-include ="'header.html'" onload='myFunction()'></div>
 </div>
  
<!-- header.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="header.html">
  Content of Header html
</script>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        alert('header loaded');
    }
}
```